# Tensorflow Hub Error - "URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution>"

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, object-detection

So I'm working on a Kaggle competition of **Object Detection**, and I'm using a model from TensorFlow Hub.

> Here's a model - ***faster_rcnn/openimages_v4/inception_resnet_v2***

> Model URL - https://tfhub.dev/google/faster_rcnn/openimages_v4/inception_resnet_v2/1

So I'm trying the below code in the notebook in Kaggle:

```
module_handle = "https://tfhub.dev/google/faster_rcnn/openimages_v4/inception_resnet_v2/1"
with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        detector = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/faster_rcnn/openimages_v4/inception_resnet_v2/1")
        image_string_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.string)
        decoded_image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string_placeholder)
        decoded_image_float = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image=decode_image,
                                                          dtype=tf.float32)
        module_input = tf.expand_dims(decoded_image_float, axis=0) # this operation inserts a dimension of 1 at the dimension index 'axis' of 'input's' shape
        result = detector(module_input, as_dict=True)
        init_ops = [tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.tables_initializer()]
        
        session = tf.Session()
        session.run(init_ops)
```

And I'm getting the error given below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1318                 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
-> 1319                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1320             except OSError as err: # timeout error

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1251         """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1252         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1253 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1297             body = _encode(body, 'body')
-> 1298         self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1299 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1246             raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1247         self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1248 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in _send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1025         del self._buffer[:]
-> 1026         self.send(msg)
   1027 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in send(self, data)
    965             if self.auto_open:
--> 966                 self.connect()
    967             else:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in connect(self)
   1413 
-> 1414             super().connect()
   1415 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in connect(self)
    937         self.sock = self._create_connection(
--> 938             (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
    939         self.sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/socket.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)
    706     err = None
--> 707     for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
    708         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/socket.py in getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags)
    751     addrlist = []
--> 752     for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
    753         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

URLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-5a767207aaa7> in <module>
      2 with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
      3     with tf.Graph().as_default():
----> 4         detector = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/faster_rcnn/openimages_v4/inception_resnet_v2/1")
      5         image_string_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.string)
      6         decoded_image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string_placeholder)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/module.py in __init__(self, spec, trainable, name, tags)
    152     """
    153     self._graph = tf_v1.get_default_graph()
--> 154     self._spec = as_module_spec(spec)
    155     self._trainable = trainable
    156 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/module.py in as_module_spec(spec)
     34     return spec
     35   elif isinstance(spec, six.string_types):
---> 36     return load_module_spec(spec)
     37   else:
     38     raise ValueError("Unknown module spec type: %r" % type(spec))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/module.py in load_module_spec(path)
     61     tf.errors.OpError: on file handling exceptions.
     62   """
---> 63   path = registry.resolver(path)
     64   return registry.loader(path)
     65 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/registry.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     40     for impl in reversed(self._impls):
     41       if impl.is_supported(*args, **kwargs):
---> 42         return impl(*args, **kwargs)
     43     raise RuntimeError(
     44         "Missing implementation that supports: %s(*%r, **%r)" % (

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/compressed_module_resolver.py in __call__(self, handle)
     86 
     87     return resolver.atomic_download(handle, download, module_dir,
---> 88                                     self._lock_file_timeout_sec())
     89 
     90   def _lock_file_timeout_sec(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/resolver.py in atomic_download(handle, download_fn, module_dir, lock_file_timeout_sec)
    413     logging.info("Downloading TF-Hub Module '%s'.", handle)
    414     tf_v1.gfile.MakeDirs(tmp_dir)
--> 415     download_fn(handle, tmp_dir)
    416     # Write module descriptor to capture information about which module was
    417     # downloaded by whom and when. The file stored at the same level as a

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/compressed_module_resolver.py in download(handle, tmp_dir)
     81       """Fetch a module via HTTP(S), handling redirect and download headers."""
     82       request = url.Request(_append_compressed_format_query(handle))
---> 83       response = self._call_urlopen(request)
     84       return resolver.DownloadManager(handle).download_and_uncompress(
     85           response, tmp_dir)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/compressed_module_resolver.py in _call_urlopen(self, request)
     94   def _call_urlopen(self, request):
     95     # Overriding this method allows setting SSL context in Python 3.
---> 96     return url.urlopen(request)
     97 
     98 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    220     else:
    221         opener = _opener
--> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    223 
    224 def install_opener(opener):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    523             req = meth(req)
    524 
--> 525         response = self._open(req, data)
    526 
    527         # post-process response

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in _open(self, req, data)
    541         protocol = req.type
    542         result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
--> 543                                   '_open', req)
    544         if result:
    545             return result

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    501         for handler in handlers:
    502             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 503             result = func(*args)
    504             if result is not None:
    505                 return result

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in https_open(self, req)
   1360         def https_open(self, req):
   1361             return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
-> 1362                 context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
   1363 
   1364         https_request = AbstractHTTPHandler.do_request_

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1319                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1320             except OSError as err: # timeout error
-> 1321                 raise URLError(err)
   1322             r = h.getresponse()
   1323         except:

URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution>
```

***Note that:*** I'm getting this error, only inside the Kaggle (running notebook inside Kaggle). I tried to run this on Google Colab and works perfectly fine.

Comment: If by trying different model URL the problem doesn't exist it means the server for the above model may be down.

Comment: Okay So Let me try another model. Thank You for the Response.

Comment: It seems to be working now again @JaiminSagar

Comment: In my case still not working. Now I am trying a different model.

Comment: I'm getting this error, only inside the Kaggle (running notebook inside Kaggle)(And I Tried different models). I tried to run this on Google Colab and works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have turned on the internet access.
[image: See here]